# How to send fetch request from HTTPS to a HTTP server : Mixed Content error

Tags: rest, http, flask, next.js, fetch

I am using a NextJs app where I am using a simple fetch to send some POST data.

We I used app on localhost it worked fine but when I put it on the server it got following error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://speechwithai.com/home' was loaded
> over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
> 'http://18.224.190.161:5000/fileToText'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The from and to are both on same IP address (https://speechwithai.com/). At the back I am running NGINX to server WebAPP at port 80 and Flask REST API at 5000. I am using Flask because I needed python libraries to process some files.

I tried multiple post but I did not find any solution. Could someone please help me?

All I want is to send a request to my FLASK API server which is running

> http://someIPAddress:5000 from https://myLiveNextJsApplication.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both servers are running behind same server and you already have nginx setup.

follow these steps

1. setup reverse proxy for flask
   with some thing like below

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 443;
    location /flask_api {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }
```

nginx configuration resides in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
.
For more information visit https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

2. configure ui to use this flask_api
   `url = https://speechwithai.com/flask_api`
3. update flask path route to use `/flask_api`

Comment: cannot downgrade the main app to http. It has to remain as https.

Comment: Updated comment, go through the solution again

Comment: thanks, this is actually what I ended up doing even before you comment but I have accepted you answer because thats how it is supposed to be solved.